# How running SoapUI from Java

Tags: java, soapui

i have problem with running SoapUI from java, I work with Eclipse 
I need run only registor test in SoapUI (project xml)

```
SoapUITestCaeRunner runner = new SoapUITestCaeRunner();
runner.setJUnitReport(true); 
runner.run();
```

In SoapUI i have "Request" and "Registor" 
How i can run only   Registor

```
Project 
   runRequest
   registor
```

Comment: Are those the test suites or cases? what is happening when you the above mentioned code?

Comment: i run test suites and i have answer was proplem in my test in soapui tanks

Answer (score 0):

Create a Soapui Project's Object using Class WsdlProject then you can use method 
WsdlTestSuite  **getTestSuiteByName**(String testSuiteName) 
Then Call run() method of WsdlTestSuite Class
WsdlTestSuiteRunner **run**(StringToObjectMap context, boolean async) 
Detail can be found [here](https://www.soapui.org/apidocs/com/eviware/soapui/impl/wsdl/WsdlProject.html)